# Internal Error while Migrating the 3.7 Sitefinity sit to 5.2?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, sitefinity-5, sitefinity-3x

I am very new to Sitefinity. Currently I created a website & deployed to IIS7 sucessfully.
But I have to migrate a website developed in Sitefinity version 3.7.

And I am having problems in deploying that site to IIS7, I searched & found the issue was in Web.Config, therefore I copied the web.Config from 5.2 project into the 3.7 project. But then I had following Error :

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

---

Previously (before changing the web.Config) I was having the 500 - Internal server error.

---

Below is the old Web.Config:[enter link description here](http://www.fileswap.com/dl/XKn8NPjtnp/)

---

Edit :

Actually my problem is that, I have the older project running under .net framework 2.0.
Therefore, I first need to upgrade the older project to 3.7 sp4, but I don't get the 3.7 sp4 download option anywhere on Sitefinity website.

Can anyone help me to upgrade my old project to 3.7 sp4.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the Sitefinity v3.7 SP4 download should be available on your account-page, if you're entitled to that edition ofcourse, by following this [link](http://www.telerik.com/account/your-products/download-list.aspx?skucid=21).

Secondly, you shouldn't have to mess with upgrading v3.7 onto another .NET version by copying/pasting the web.config from your 5.2 project or exchanging dll's. Changing the app-pool and a possible rebuild should do the trick.

You can migrate the running 3.7 project, either through Sitefinity Project manager automatically or following the manual steps provided in the [documentation](http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/installation-and-administration-guide/migrating-your-sitefinity-3-7-project/manual-migration-setup) by just extracting the Module3.7_SP4_NET35.zip file into the 3.7 folder and add just the following lines to the 3.7 web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

If you could elaborate more on the 500 error you received prior to changing the web.config or email me, maybe we can find out what's causing it...

Jochem.